# SQL Server from two dates get working(excluding saturdays and sundays) days group by month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two dates from 2019/07/26 and 2019/08/08 from these dates i want result

```
Year  Month  ActualDays  WorkingDays
------------------------------------
2019    07       06           04
2019    08       08           06


DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME

SET @start = '2019-07-26'
SET @end = '2019-08-08'

;WITH c(d) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end) + 1 )
        DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)-1, @start)
    FROM 
        sys.all_columns
) 
SELECT 
    YEAR(t.[date]), MONTH(t.[date]), t.[days]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [date] = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, d), 0), 
         [days] = COUNT(*)
     FROM 
         c 
     GROUP BY 
         DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, d)
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 
         d, NULL           
     FROM 
         c) AS t
WHERE 
    t.[days] IS NOT NULL
```

From this I will get days group by month and year I need working days

Comment: if you are working with weekday / weekend days, best is to have your own calendar table

Comment: I'm confused by the 6 & 8 in the `ActualDays` column.  Where did you come up with those numbers?  Is that Actual Days (including Weekends) in the given month?  Same for Working Days (all days minus Weekends) in the given month?

Comment: @Airn5475  2019/07/26 to 2019/07/31= 6 days same 2019/08/01 to 2019/08/08= 8 days but I need only working days excluding sat & sun

Comment: @Vivek sorry, that's a big confusing.  Can you update your question with that information and perhaps give us a code sample as suggested by @Deltapimol?

Comment: @Airn5475 i have edited with code..please help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE = '20190701'
      , @enddate DATE   = '20190716'
DECLARE @temp TABLE(thedate DATE, DoCount INT);

WITH CTE (thedate) AS 
(
  SELECT @startdate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, thedate)
    FROM CTE
   WHERE thedate < @enddate
)     
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT thedate,CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, [thedate]) IN (1,7) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM CTE

SELECT YEAR(thedate),MONTH(thedate),
COUNT(DoCount) AS ActualDays,
SUM(DoCount)    WorkingDays
FROM @temp
GROUP BY YEAR(thedate),
MONTH(thedate)
```